# How to make environment variable visible to non root users inside the container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to pass on environment variables to be read from an XML file inside a docker container running wildly app service and hosted inside REHL 7 image.

What I've done so far:

1. I've created an environment file as key value pair, for example: `FILESERVICE_MAX_POOL_SIZE=5`
2. I am running docker by referencing the environment file: `docker run -d --env-file ./ENV_VARIABLES <myImage>`
3. In the Dockerfile I copy the xml template I need: `COPY dockerfiles/standalone.xml /opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`
4. Inside the XML template I'm trying to reference the environment variable:                         `<max-pool-size>${env.FILESERVICE_MAX_POOL_SIZE}</max-pool-size>`

I can see those environment variables inside the running container as root but not as the wildly user which needs them. How can I make an attribute visible to a specific user other than root ?

Clearly I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here just not sure what ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what is your images based on?

Comment: It is based on REHL 7, I've also updated the question

Comment: How are you testing root vs user in the container? Please include the two run commands and env output from each.

Comment: By elevating to root and ensuring I'm root with whoami. I then run env as root and I see the attributes. I then run su - wildfly and repeat the process

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: wildfly couldn't see the attributes because in my startup script I didn't add the -E flag for sudo to preserve environment variables.

Comment: Nice, maybe `envsubst` can also help basically you can `source <env--file>` and then `envsubst < standalone_template.xml > standalone.xml`